# Is it possible for a macro to generate code based on the content of a file?

Tags: io, macros, rust

I'd like to write a macro that is parametrized by a file path. At compile time it reads that file and emits Rust code based on its content. Is this possible?

I've found [`include_bytes!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/std/macro.include_bytes!.html) but it's unclear how I could consume its result during compile-time instead of just splicing in the contents into the generated code as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is probably possible, you are certainly asking for trouble: For example, cargo will not be able to tell if the "wrapping" code needs recompilation after the "wrapped" code changed because it does not consider that file to be part of the source tree.

You should consider either using a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) or good old Makefiles, which are designed exactly for that purpose.